# Finding the determinant of a Matrix A.

Tags: linear-algebra

compute det A where

$$A=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 1 & 2 & -1 \\
        2 & 5 & -7 & 3\\
        0 & 3 & 6 & 2\\
        -2 & -5 & 4 & -2\\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

What I know first is that you have to use the formula called co-factor expansion

$detA$ = $a_{i1}C_{i1} +a_{i2}C_{i2} +...+ a_{in}C_{in}$

So I do that and I substitute and get this

$detA$ = $a_{21}C_{11} +a_{12}C_{i12}$

$R_4=R_4-R_2$

$$A=
        \begin{bmatrix}
       \bbox[yellow] 0 & 1 & 2 & -1 \\
       \bbox[yellow] 2 &\bbox[yellow] 5 & \bbox[yellow]-7 & \bbox[yellow]3\\
       \bbox[yellow] 0 & 3 & 6 & 2\\
       \bbox[yellow] 0 & 0 & -3 & 1\\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

After row factoring I get

$$A=-2
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 2 & -1  \\
        3 & 6 & 2 \\
        0 & -3 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

What is giving me problems is I understand the co-factor expansion you literally choose any row and column to reduce. But where does the -2 come from the formula?

Comment: I don't see why $A$ suddenly becomes a $3\times 3$ matrix.

Comment: The minus sign comes from the definition of co-factor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use row reduction instead:
$$\det A=-\begin{vmatrix}
2&5&-7&3\\
-2&-5&4&-2\\
0&1&2&-1\\
0&3&6&2
\end{vmatrix}=
-\begin{vmatrix}
2&5&-7&3\\
0&0&-3&1\\
0&1&2&-1\\
0&0&0&5
\end{vmatrix}=
\begin{vmatrix}
2&5&-7&3\\
0&1&2&-1\\
0&0&-3&1\\
0&0&0&5
\end{vmatrix}=2\cdot1\cdot(-3)\cdot5=\color{red}{-30}.$$

Comment: Quick question can row reduction always work for the solution?

Comment: I see you multiplied all the pivots to get the determinant, once it is in row echelon form.I did not know you could do that.

Comment: For  a triangular  matrix, the determinant is the product of the diagonal elements. Note that for a determinant of size $n$, the row reduction method requires $O(n^3)$ operations, while Laplace expansion requires $O(n!)$…